# How to check if NamedTuple is in list?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, namedtuple

I tried to check if an inctance of a NamedTuple "Transition" is equal to any object in the list "self.memory".

Here is the code I tried to run:

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import random
import torch as t

Transition = NamedTuple('Transition', state=t.Tensor, action=int, reward=int, next_state=t.Tensor, done=int, hidden=t.Tensor)


class ReplayMemory:

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.memory = []
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.position = 0

    def store(self, *args):
        print(self.memory == Transition(*args))
        if Transition(*args) in self.memory:
            return
    if len(self.memory) < self.capacity:
        self.memory.append(None)
    self.memory[self.position] = Transition(*args)
    ...
```

And here is the output:

```
False
False
```

And the error I got:

```
   ...
        if Transition(*args) in self.memory:
    RuntimeError: bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

This seems weird to me because the print is telling me that the "==" operation returns a boolean.

How could this be done correctly?

Thank you

Edit:

*args is a tuple that consists of

```
torch.Size([16, 12])
int
int
torch.Size([16, 12])
int
torch.Size([4])
```

Comment: what does `Transition(*args)` return?

Comment: Can you show us the values in `*args`?

Comment: @Kenan it returns a NamedTuple as specified in line 5 of the first code block

Comment: Your problem is equality of the values *inside* the named tuple, not the tuple itself. The `in` operator compares the single tuple against each element in `self.memiry`. In contrast, the `==` operator compares the tuple against the list, which is trivially `False` because the types are not equal; no elements are compared in this case.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi how is it possible that the assertion prints a single boolean though?

Comment: @LukeC The print runs an entirely different comparison. It compares the tuple against the list, not its elements.

Comment: @LukeC something to note when using `==`, `a=5;b=[];a==b` -> `False` and `a!=b` -> True, however the comparison doesn't make sense right

Answer (score 1):

I believe the you should explicitly define equality.

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import random
import torch as t


class Sample(NamedTuple):
    state: t.Tensor
    action: int

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return bool(t.all(self.state == other.state)) and self.action == other.action
```